# GPIO push button popout webpage

Tags: gpio, python, output

I have a project that I connected a push button to RPi 4's GPIO, and if I push the button it writes out "Button pushed". I wrote this code in python. Now I want this code to run in a webpage. So I have a button on my webpage, if I push that button, that executes my python code, and if I push my GPIO button, the webpage displays, the "Button pushed". I have Lamp, and Flask also installed.

**The python code looks like this:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import datetime
time=datetime.datetime.now()
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def button_callback(channel):
    output="Time is %s and the button was pushed" % (time)
    print(output)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback)
message = input("Press enter to quit\n\n")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Thanks for all of your advices!

Comment: Look up CGI scripting.

Comment: ... or use PHP instead of python3